# save in array vars of loaded files Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have

```
load t1.txt;
load t2.txt;
load t3.txt;
load t4.txt;

data=t1;

vector =[ 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ];
for i = vector
    [TempFlag, MemberInd] = ismember( i, vector );
    fprintf('vector(%d) is %d\n', MemberInd, i);
    scatter( data(:,1),data(:,2))
end
```

if I want to do the above loop with all 4 files, How would you load them in a vector or something, so with each iteration it does other data?.

So I want to avoid:

```
data = t2;

(loop)

data = t3;

(loop)
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `data=1`, yet used it like a matrix in this line :`scatter( data(:,1),data(:,2))`... that should've given you a `Index exceeds matrix dimensions` error.

Assuming that was a typo, and that you just want to do it for different values of `data`, use nested loops.

```
data=[1,2,3,4];
vector=[2,3,4,5,6];

for i=data
    for j=vector
        <do stuff here>
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

If your files are named `t-{a,e,i,o,u}` and the data variables are named the same, then you can try the following:

```
fileName={'ta','te','ti','to','tu'};
for i=1:length(fileName)
    dummy=load(sprintf('%s.txt',fileName{i}));
    eval(sprintf('data=dummy.%s',fileName{i}));
    <other stuff here>
end
```

Comment: If the name files are not number is it the same?

Comment: `A= load ta.txt;
B= load te.txt;
C= load ti.txt;
D= load to.txt;
E= load tu.txt;

sets=[ta,te,ti,to,tu];`

Comment: are `ta`,`tb`, etc all the same size?

Comment: nope, they are kind of different, is it possible using Matlab?

Comment: try the edited answer... the loop `j=vector` goes in the `other stuff here` section.